# From localserver database to embedded database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java, MySQL: Is there a way to embed a MySQL server with a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791417/java-mysql-is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-mysql-server-with-a-java-program)

I made a java program that uses a mysql database that works on a local server (XAMPP). When I build my project (NETBEANS), it will only functions if the local server is running. So is there any way to make my program run without the need of a local server. Can the database be embedded in the Jar. file to make my app a Standalone. I appreciated your help ! Thanks

Comment: See this answer: [is there a way to embed a mysql server with a java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791417/java-mysql-is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-mysql-server-with-a-java-program)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is: No, the MySQL database cannot be "embedded" in a jar file.

If you have built your application to require a connection to a MySQL database, then you will need a MySQL database server running somewhere. (The MySQL server doesn't have to be local to the box; you can connect to a remote MySQL server, although that adds a dependency, so may not be the way you want to go for a "standalone" application.

If you need an "embedded" database for a "standalone" application, you might want to check out some different databases, e.g.

Java H2 database engine: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Apache Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/

---

MySQL has stopped development and support for MySQL Connector/MJX  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-mxj/en/connector-mxj.html  which wasn't a truly embedded database; it was really a mechanism to automatically start a MySQL instance and initialize a database when a JDBC connection was requested.

Comment: Or use Derby, which is available in every JVM since version 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input ! Helps a lot.