# how to embedd mysql in grails standalone application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, grails

I am creating a grails standalone application with with embedded tomcat server
the application works fine with embedded tomcat server.

But i need to integrate embedded mysql with the application.
Any tutorial or any hint to start with is very much appreciated.

The points i need to figure out

1. how can i configure my standalone application to use embedded mysql
2. whether mysql can be configured as embedded database or not

Comment: Is mysql a must? HyperSQL a also is embeddable: http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html

Comment: @heikkim : i know apache derby , SQLite and Hsql are the alternatives , but i need to do it with mysql only , any help ??

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791417/java-mysql-is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-mysql-server-with-a-java-program) it seems that you're looking for [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-mxj/en/connector-mxj.html).

Comment: Michels : thanx for your input , nut i already tried it , doesnt helps

Answer (score 0):

For fresh versions of grails (3,4) the plugin for embedded mysql exist
https://github.com/purpleraven/embedded-mysql-grails-plugin